# $R=\mathbb Z[\sqrt3]. x=2-sqrt3, then {x^n:n is an integer} is an infinite set of distinct values.

Tags: ring-theory

Let  $R=\mathbb Z[\sqrt3]$

I would like to show that when $x=2-\sqrt3$, then $\{x^n:n \in \mathbb Z\}$ is an infinite set of distinct values. How should I do this?

Thank you!

Comment: For square roots, the square root of u is represented as 'dollar sign' \sqrt{u} 'dollar sign' $\to \sqrt{u}$. I'm not sure about set notation, though, so it might be best if I leave that to someone else to edit.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate that!

Answer (score 0):

If for some $n\in \mathbb Z$ $\{(2-\sqrt3)^n:n\in \mathbb Z\}$ does not have distinct values then

$(2-\sqrt3)^i=(2-\sqrt3)^j;1\leq i,j\leq n$

then since $2-\sqrt3$ is invertible in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt 3]$ so $(2-\sqrt3)^{i-j}=1$

which is true only for $i=j$

Comment: Thanks- just one thing, how do you know that that is only true for i=j? Surely we have to show that there is no other power of (2-sqrt3) equal to 1?

Comment: no if $i\neq j $ then LHS will contain rational and irrational terms both whereas RHS only has rational terms